# how do i redirect user to the user page and admin to the admin page in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Whenever i logged in i have redirected all to 'welcome.php'. But if i want user to redirect on user page and admin to redirect on admin page. what can I do. ?  i have defined types of users already just want to redirect them separately. for eg. user and admin option is there when a  new user gets register/signup.

in UsersController.php

```
  public function login()
 {
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('login');
    $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
    $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'welcome',
        ]);
        
        return $this->redirect($redirect);
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
    }

}
```

signup.php

```
    <div class="mb-3" id="div2">

        <label for="utype" class="text-gray-600  mb-2 "> 
          Usertype</label>
        <div class="form-check ">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="utype" value="admin"  
                 class=" px-3 py-2  border border-gray-300 rounded-md 
                 " />;
             Admin </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="utype" value="user"   
                 class="px-3 py-2  border border-gray-300 rounded-md"  
                 checked/>;
            User </label>
        </div>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: If your result is valid, use `$this->Authentication->getIdentity()` to get the details of the logged-in user, and set `$redirect` based on that.

Comment: tysm greg schmidt. it works exactly what i wanted to be

Comment: $uid = $this->Auth->user('your_field');. https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html